# How to replace strike tag to input type text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to replacement strike element to input type text?
I have no idea at this time if any kind of solution please tell me here!

**HTML Text** :

```
In the <b>joy</b> of <strike>other</strike>, lies our <strike>own</strike>.
```

**replace Text :**

```
In the <b>joy</b> of <input type="text">, lies our <input type="text">.
```

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask :)

Comment: What exactly is the question? How to replace the `<strike>` html with `<input>` tags using javascript?

Comment: [this][1] is related problem. Giving you a clue to solve your problem 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444041/replace-node-name

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question well, you want this?

```
$('strike').each(function(){
    $(this).replaceWith("<input type=\"text\" value=\"" + $(this).text() + "\" />");

});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M88u4/

Comment: it can be possible without using each iteration? i want to using for loop at this condition.

Comment: why wouldn't you want to use `each`? I mean, if you're already using other jQuery functions to replace the strike tag already, why not use `each`?  Can you clarify why you want to use a for() loop?

Answer (score 0):

Just add following jQuery statement

```
 // search all strike element and replace it 
 $('strike').replaceWith(function(){
        //create input element
        var input = $('<input>',{
            type: 'text',
            value: $(this).html()
        });
        //replace with input element
        return input;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML

```
<div id="test">
    In the <b>joy</b> of <strike>other</strike>, lies our <strike>own</strike>.
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(function(){
    var strikes = $('#test').children('strike');
    var inputText = "<input type='text' />";
    strikes.each(function(){
        $(this).replaceWith(inputText);
    });
});
```